# How to download dataset from AWS Data Exchange?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I subscribed to the [free synthetic dataset](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-3namitss5jmsy?ref_=srh_res_product_title).

Now I have "Revision ID", "Revision ARN", "Data set ID" and 28 CSV files which I can not download in a pack. I must manually download them one after another or I can export them all to the AWS e3 (I do not want to do that).

Is there a way to download it all in a single archive or somehow automate the process via AWS S3 CLI?

[image]

I've tried

```
./venv/bin/awscliv2 s3 cp s3://arn:aws:dataexchange:us-east-1::data-sets/b0b14e86c092855166507c15e045b844/revisions/6011536d595840f7bd4412fca59e0f6b/assets/7cd4a5cbedb0c5c83e37c20f668b3708 ./


fatal error: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "arn:aws:dataexchange:us-east-1::data-sets": Bucket
name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN
matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:]
[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:
[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]
{1,63}$"
```

**UPD:** I've found a [python snippet](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dataexchange-api-samples/blob/master/subscribers/python/download-entitled-assets/download-entitled-assets.py), which uses `boto3` and creates a temporary bucket in the process.

**UPD 2:**: From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/latest/userguide/jobs.html#exporting-assets

> There are two ways you can export assets from a published revision of a product:
>
> - To an Amazon S3 bucket that you have permissions to access.
> - By using a signed URL.

Therefore, I can't do that stuff without bucket through AWS CLI, but I can use `EXPORT_ASSET_TO_SIGNED_URL`

**UPD 3:** I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/banderlog/cd14886421cf1cfcbdca7e8aab9dc584) for downloading a dataset from AWS DataExchange via signed urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why u using such complicated aws s3 cp. 2 line script can be something like

```
#syncing all files in folder to local directory ~/csvs/
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname/<folder>/ ~/csvs/   
#you can zip or tar full foder whatever u want 
zip ~/csvs csvs.zip
```

Comment: Nice point for buckets, I will use it :) But problem is the dataset lies in AWS Data Exchange service. I wondered is there a way to get it without using a bucket as a middleman.

Comment: In the screenshot u shared; there is a button on top "Export to S3".. It will copy all those to your s3 bucket; then u can just download to local ( or to EC2 ) and zip them.